# Threejs: Applying material depending on an attribute on the BufferrGeometry

Tags: three.js

I know it is possible to assign multiple materials depending on some values on the `Face3` object, like:

```js
var materialA = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ccee});
var materialB = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFF0000, map: buildingTexture});
var materials = [materialA, materialB];
geometry.materials = [materialA, materialB];
assignUVs(geometry);

for(var i = 0; i< geometry.faces.length; i++){
    if(geometry.faces[i].normal.y >= 0.99){
        geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 0;
    }else{
        geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 1;
    }

}
var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
```

But let's say that I've an attribute per vertex (fulfilled with the correct value while I was creating the geometry) on a `BufferGeometry` instance,like:

geometry.addAttribute( 'isLeaf', new THREE.BufferAttribute(palmBuffers.isLeaf,1));

is it possible to apply a material depending on that attribute?

I know that an easier way would be to create a buffer that contains value per face, and not per vertex, I just wanted to know if there is a way to do it starting from per vertex attributes.

Comment: You're probably looking for a shader. A shader can look at the value of a vertex attribute, and change the color (and a lot more!) of the related fragment(s). The example [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shader.html) is a simple plane, with a shader that uses time as an input to update the colors drawn to the plane.

Comment: I just realized my link was a poor example. [This example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_rawshader.html) show (in a very basic way) how to access the `position` and `color` attributes of the `THREE.BufferGeometry`.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I know what shaders are ;) Probably i did not explained myself correctly. I was looking for a way to assign the material (a threejs built-in shader, like MeshStandardMaterial) to a geometry depending on the values per vertices stored in a Float32Array. It turned out it was easier to just create a buffer containing a value for each face.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I've implemented is to create a buffer with the same dimension of the number of the faces for that geometry. Then I fullfill the buffer with the value that i need, then I use the values in the buffers to decide whic material to apply for every face.